# Not getting push notification on lollipop android devices using FCM

Tags: android, notifications

I am using FCM for Push notification and it works fine with pre-lollipop devices but not getting notification in lollipop.

Here is my code.

(Manifest)services:-

```
<service android:name=".fcmlistenerservices.MyInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".fcmlistenerservices.MyFcmListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

This is service to display notification:

```
public class MyFcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message){
        String from = message.getFrom();
        Map data = message.getData();
        Log.d("MyTag", "From: " + from);
        Log.d("MyTag", "Notification Message Body: " + data.get(""));
        //logic to display notification
        //Toast.makeText(MyFcmListenerService.this,""+message.getData(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Firebase : ", "Notification from firebase: "+data.get("message"));
        sendNotification((String) data.get("message"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving the message in onMessageReceived method?

Comment: Receiving in pre-lollipop devices but not in Lollipop devices

Comment: So, you are not even getting those logs printed in lollipop devices?

Comment: Check if you Really subscribe ( send token to your server) ( in onTokenRefresh() )

Comment: please check/post your project level and application level gradle file dependencies. Mostly check with targeted version dependencies